# Dynamically change text color with jquery and spectrum.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<span>` tag, `<span class="output render" id="text1"></span>`, that I would like to be dynamically controlled by spectrum.js to change the color.

The span is rendered from this jquery:

```
$("#text_submit").submit(
    function(event) {
        $("#text1").html($("#1").val());
    }
);
```

To get the color picker to affect the span I tried:

```
$(".output render").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
```

The above creates only an HTML text input box where the color picker used to be (how I got the color picker to appear is below). But it has no effect on the `<span>`. What can I do with jQuery to make this happen?

I used the code below to make the color picker appear:

```
$("#picker1").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
```

which made the color picker appear where this HTML tag is `<input type='input' id="picker1" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), you need to explicitly change the color using events.

For example:

```
function updateColor(element, color) {
    var hexColor = "transparent";
    if (color) hexColor = color.toHexString();
    $(element).css("color", hexColor);
}

$("#picker1").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    hide: function (color) {
        updateColor(".output.render", color);
    }
});
```

Also note that to select an element with both `output` and `render` classes, you need to use the selector `.output.render`.

Here's an working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/mjHUD/

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be the following:

```
$("#picker1").spectrum("set", "red");
```