# Replacing multiple CSS color values simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I am making a website where the user can select the colors of the page. The site is using only two colors. A background color and a color for everything else. (Text, Borders and background colors in separate boxes.)

I try to get spectrum.js to change all colors other than the background color and text over the colored boxes.

I am trying to modify the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820044/dynamically-change-text-color-with-jquery-and-spectrum-js) by ariel.

```
var initialColor = "#E84E1B";
$("body").css("color", initialColor);
$("divwithfill").css("border-color", initialColor);

function updateColor(element, color) {
    $(element).css("color", (color ? color.toHexString() : ""));
}

$("#colorChanger").spectrum({
    color: initialColor,
    move: function (color) {
        updateColor(".output.render", color);
    },
    hide: function (color) {
        updateColor(".output.render", color);
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mjHUD/31/
This is a  copy of a fiddle found of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820044/dynamically-change-text-color-with-jquery-and-spectrum-js). I am trying to change all off the #E84E1B values to the color chosen by the user.

EDIT:
To specify: I want the user to be able to use #colorChanger to change all CSS values that are # E84E1B by default. (Includes background-color and border) All CSS values with # c6c6c6 I want to be unchanged. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Whats the problem? Its not clear

Comment: you can do this much more efficiently and more versatile (since you can target also pseudo-elements) by [dynamic stylesheet](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) with the updated css values

Comment: Are you tied to using spectrum?

Comment: No i am not. It seemed like a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you can't actually select elements by their css values, but you can access the stylesheets attached to the document and do some pretty funky things with them.

A little bit of a different method here. No extra classes have to be added. No external libraries required. Basically...

- Loop through every stylesheet attached to the document.
- Loop through every rule in those stylesheets.
- Loop through every property in those rules.
- Test the value of each property against the input string.
- If the value matches the input string

  - Set the value of the property to the new color.
- When the looping is done, return the input color to save it so we can start all over again.

```js
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    rgb = 'rgb(';
    rgb += parseInt(result[1], 16) + ", ";
    rgb += parseInt(result[2], 16) + ", ";
    rgb += parseInt(result[3], 16) + ')';
    return rgb;
}

var initialColor1 = hexToRgb("#C6C6C6");
var initialColor2 = hexToRgb("#E84E1B");
function chameleon(hex, initial) {
    var rgb = hexToRgb(hex);
    var stylesheets = document.styleSheets, stylesheet, i;
    for (i = 0; (stylesheet = stylesheets[i]); i++) {
        var rules = stylesheet.cssRules, rule, j;
        if(!rules) continue;
        for(j = 0; (rule = rules[j]); j++) {
            var styles = rule.style, style, k;
            for(k = 0; (style = styles[k]); k++) {
                var value = styles.getPropertyValue(style);
                if(initial == value) {
                    styles.setProperty(style, rgb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rgb;
}
document.getElementById('picker1').oninput = function(e) {
    initialColor1 = chameleon(e.target.value, initialColor1);
}
document.getElementById('picker2').oninput = function(e) {
    initialColor2 = chameleon(e.target.value, initialColor2);
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #C6C6C6; color: #E84E1B;}#divwithfill { height: 50px; width: 50px; border: solid 1px #E84E1B; background-color: #E84E1B; color: #C6C6C6; }#divnofill { height: 50px; width: 50px; border: solid 1px #E84E1B;}
```

```html
<span class="output render" id="text1">sample text</span>
<div id="divwithfill">sample text</div>
<div id="divnofill">sample text</div>
<label for="picker1">Color #1: <input type="color" id="picker1" value="#C6C6C6"></label><br>
<label for="picker2">Color #2: <input type="color" id="picker2" value="#E84E1B"></label>
```

Comment: You must be a wizard!

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for you that might be easier just using plain old javascript and css. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/haan5yv4/3/)

Some example html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box changeable">
        Sample Text
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="box unchangeable">
        Sample Text
    </div>
</div>
<div>border<input id="border-colorer" type="color" /></div>
<div>text<input id="text-colorer" type="color" /></div>
<div>background<input id="background-colorer" type="color" /></div>
```

Set up your css like this to inherit colors from the container:

```
#container .changeable {
    background-color:inherit;
    color:inherit;
    border-color:inherit;
}
.box {
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Then set up listeners for the color-selects which will set the style on just the container.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
var changeable = container.querySelectorAll('.changeable');

document.getElementById('border-colorer').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    [].forEach.call(changeable, function(el){
        el.style['border-color'] = e.target.value;
    })
});

document.getElementById('text-colorer').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    [].forEach.call(changeable, function(el){
       el.style.color = e.target.value;
    })
});

document.getElementById('background-colorer').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    [].forEach.call(changeable, function(el){
        el.style['background-color'] = e.target.value;
    })
});
```

Now when you change the color in a select, the style will be set on the only the changeable elements in the container.